# ajax: How to post a message without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

could you explain the basis on how to post a message (like facebook or even stackoverflow) that don't reload their page but they shows the comment instantly ?

How that works?

Add1:

I know how ajax works, I would know how to do this particular stuff with ajax, ie posting a comment to a database and showing it without reloading the page

Comment: You should Google ajax.  Look at the wiki entry.

Comment: i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: I know how ajax works, I would know how to do this particular stuff with ajax, ie posting a comment to a database and showing it without reloading the page

Comment: If you want close this at least explain WHY

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the entire point of Ajax is to be asynchronous.  This means that the request fires, but a user can still use the page from which the Ajax is invoked.  When the response comes back, the javascript handling the ajax will update the relevant part of the page.  So how to do it, really basic and simple

1)  have a button with a javascript handler on it.  When clicked, the button js
2)  executes the ajax request.  When the request returns
3)  javascript updates the page, with the comment in your example.

Comment: @yes123 "It depends" it might be an HTML snippet with innerHTML (ick) that replaces a designated area or a custom DOM manipulation (which may or may not use appendChild directly or indirectly) designed for a particular action, etc.

Comment: @yes123 there are many ways to do it, that is one of them. Its up to you.

Comment: I opened this question not to get a vague answer =/

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code http posts to a backend script (page) that you have set up. That page does stuff and then returns the result for the javascript to use for modifying the DOM on the page.